# Consistantly insert rows from top of page in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to setup a workbook that will contain many rows of data. In order to keep things chronological I would like to consistently (or always) insert a new row of data at the top of the spreadsheet, instead of having to scroll down to the last entry. I should end up with the most recent data on top.

The question is, can I do this without having to right click on the first row (in between the header row) and chose Insert Row or right click on the cell Choose Insert, Entire Row. I'm envisioning here a way to setup like a blank form row that I could enter my info for the entire row and hit a button (or look for an Enter key in the last column's cell) and this would insert that row information into that top row that I keep referencing. Is this possible? Am I dreaming here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes sir. You can indeed. 
All you need to do is to record a macro in excel that will do this job for you and paste the data to the first row.

Copy the data you want to paste and start a macro. you can assign a macro to the custom button on the ribbon. this way it will only be single left mouse button click.

Macro should look similiar to this:

```
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

You will find a tips on how to use buttons in excel here: [click](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-using-macro-through-buttons/)
And here is a guide to add it to the quick access toolbar : [click](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-an-excel-2010-macro-to-the-quick-access.html)

Comment: beautiful. thanks. got it to insert and remove the old data.