# Excel Consistently Insert Blank Row at Top of Sheet (after frozen first row)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to create an Excel sheet that'll have a blank row at the top for my coworkers to request things. Unlike this post "[Consistantly insert rows from top of page in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/463024/consistantly-insert-rows-from-top-of-page-in-excel)" my excel sheet has a frozen first row as labels for the columns. Either way, the code didn't work for me anyways, so I would like clarification on the previous post as well.

Comment: Do you want to insert rows in the frozen pane or below the frozen pane?

Comment: Below the frozen pane. Adding a new "item" to be ordered under the "item column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved with a little modification to the explanation you are referring to. First I froze the first row. Then I recorded a macro that inserts a row above the second row. This is the code.

```
Sub NewRow()
        Rows("2:2").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Then I added a button by clicking on the developers tab and insert. Then I connected the macro to the button. For a detailed explanation: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283.

You should also be careful that your button doesn't resize when inserting new rows, this can be prevented by right-clicking the button and choose edit. Then you have to go the properties tab and select "don't move or size cells".

Now you have a fully functional button that inserts rows below your frozen pane.

Comment: Cheers for the help! It works great. There are two issues, though. 1) The frozen top row is formatted so that the background color is distinguishable. Is there a way to insert the row at the top without carrying over the top row format? 2) Also, I have this legend that is in column G. Is there a way to freeze that also like you can with the button?

Comment: You can easily freeze the legend if you insert it in a text box. For the other problem I will have to search a bit further..

Comment: The easy (not VBA solution) to the background colour is to make a blank row 2 and then hide it. Then change the macro to Rows("3:3").Select :).

Comment: cheers for the info. The text that I have has multiple conditions -- certain words creates different fills, text colors, etc. I tried with the text box, but the fill only works for the whole box.

Comment: You could try to cut and paste the legend with the macro by adding the following line (assuming your legend is in G1:G10):

Range(“G1:G10”).Cut before you insert the rows.

Range("G1:G10").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats after the rows are inserted.

I hope this answers your question. If this is everything you want, can you then update your question and i'll update my answer so that you can mark it as correct answer

Comment: That may work. I also just made a screen shot photo, cropped it, and pasted it with properties to not move.

Comment: You've answered the original question. I'm sure you can mark it as correct.

Comment: I can't mark my own answer as correct. Only you, who asked the question, can mark it as correct.

Comment: Mitchthan, how do I mark it as correct?

Comment: There is a V below where you can downvote my answer, if you click on it, it will be marked as correct